# Ruby on Rails : Ajax response to file other than default action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want two actions in my Controller to return to view file showcomment.js.erb in case of ajax call and its functioning fine in showcooment.js.erb. But I want to return the view from delete action also to showcomment.js.erb. How can it be done?

```
 def showcomment
       @article = Article.find(params[:id])
       @comments = @article.comments
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js
        end
    end


    def deletecomment
    @comment = comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
          respond_to do |format|
          format.js
        end

end
```

Comment: Just create deletecomment.js.erb, it should be rendered.

Comment: i want dont want to create duplicate code so want to use the same file

Comment: Ahh, I see the updated question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def deletecomment
    @comment = comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{ render :action => 'showcomment' }
    end
end
```